# Clean Code Architecture in Golang

Tags: golang, архитектура, cleancode

Начал изучать реализацию Clean Code Architecture в Golang, и наткнулся на 2 варианта. Код в обоих выглядит одинаково, однако организация пакетов отличается. Выглядят они примерно так:

1. [image: first]
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как все таки лучше? Какие различия у подходов? Плюсы? Минусы?

Comment: Если не смотреть, в какой области проект, то, скорее, первый подход, т.к. его проще понять

Comment: @dikey0ficial Что скажите об ответе @pac-ulla?

Answer (score 0):

Первый способ хорош для маленьких монолитных проектов, в которых не предполагается значительное расширение набора функций. Есть сервис 1 и сервис 2, и баста. Тогда можно декомпозировать сервис на два сервиса, обработчик на два обработчика и репозиторий на два репозитория. Всё наглядно. Но при увеличении числа сервисов усложнится поддержка декомпозиций. Обязательно начнутся миграции кода из сервиса в сервис, с которыми нужно параллельно мигрировать обработчики и репозитории. После пяти-семи сервисов захочется изолировать не по функционалу сервис/обработчик/репозиторий, а по компонентам. То есть второй способ.

Второй способ хорош для тех проектов, в которых предполагается разработка большого количества компонентов. Все компоненты одинаково структурированы и независимы друг от друга. Я рекомендую сразу приучаться делать именно так.

Единственное, меня смущает корневой пакет `internal` - как планируется получать доступ к методам из этих пакетов?

Comment: Почему в первом случае миграции кода обязательно начнутся и будут доставлять проблемы, а во втором нет?

Comment: На счёт internal, а зачем может понадобиться доступ к этим пакетам? И если не в internal, то как бы вы организовали структуру пакетов?